# jQuery (maybe) horizontally fix element, but vertically scroll it

Tags: jquery, positioning

I know I've seen this done somewhere, but I can't find it anywhere.

Basically, I have a side scroller (here: http://www.allisonnavon.com) that I'm putting together.

The main problem is if the browser window is just a bit too short on height, the site will scroll vertically and cover up the title that is supposed to be fixed.

I guess the other possibility is to auto-resize the images if the window's height doesn't match the site, but I want to avoid that if I can. Thanks.

Comment: Could we see some code? maybe you can postion:relative

Comment: What browser/OS combination hides the title, because FF3.6/OSX works just fine.

Comment: Who honestly has a window that small, whats your target audience?

Comment: I agree, I designed the site pretty small so it will fit most browsers. The target audience is most likely design agencies, which will have larger monitors. I'll probably just set a background to this div so it at least doesn't get lost in the images...

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quick and dirty solution add the following class to your css

```
.shader {position:fixed; width: 100%; height: 160px;background: #F9F6E5; top: 0px;left: 0px;}
```

and a div width this class just after the opening container div

```
<div class="container">
<!--add this -->
<div class="shader"></div>
<!--end add -->
<!-- text and image -->
```