# Is there a css3 way to fix a <thead> on the y-axis, let it scroll on the x-axis?

Tags: html, scroll, position

This has been asked a zillion times: [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2382083/fix-thead-on-page-scroll),  [**there**,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4334205/how-can-i-tell-iscroll-that-a-tbody-should-scroll-and-vanish-behind-a-thead) and  [**the other place**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3938679/jquery-maybe-horizontally-fix-element-but-vertically-scroll-it) just on SO. Yet there's no real good answer that I can find.

<recap> Often I have tables that are vertically much deeper than the viewport. I'd like to be able to scroll the table's `<tbody>` while its `<thead>` remains fixed and visible. Some of these tables are also much wider than the viewport. Here I want the table's `<thead>` to scroll horizontally.

To get the effect, I have dozens of lines of JS, including `setInterval( )` calls to check `scrollLeft` and `scrollTop`, so that I can reposition a *copy* of `<thead>`<sup>1</sup>. It works but it's a huge, ungainly, frail and unmaintainable pain in the ass.</recap>

**Question:** Is there some straightforward css3 way, existent or emerging or proposed, that I can use to get a a table's `<thead>` and `<tbody>` to scroll horizontally and vertically, yet independently of each other?
Thanks!

---

<sup>1</sup> Why `setInterval( )`? Because IE doesn't uniformly deliver `onScroll` events, you silly; *everybody* knows that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a dirty way would be to put the header table in a separate div like:

```
<div class="header">
<table>
    <thead><tr><td>#</td><td>v</td></tr></thead>
</table>
</div>
```

Then body in the another div like:

```
<div class="body">
    <table>
        <tbody>
            <tr><td>1</td><td>a</td></tr>
            <tr><td>1</td><td>a</td></tr>
            <tr><td>1</td><td>a</td></tr>
            <tr><td>1</td><td>a</td></tr>
            <tr><td>1</td><td>a</td></tr>         
    </tbody>
</table> 
</div>
```

Now you can give a fixed height to body `div` and set `oveflow` to `auto`. like:

```
table{border:0px solid #ccc;height:30px;}
table tr td{border:1px solid #ccc;padding:5px;}
div.body{height:70px;overflow:auto;border-bottom:1px solid #ccc;}
```

here is a working example I did in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/naveed_ahmad/2jfKA/)

Comment: That is real nice, for sure. The parameter I left out (sneaky me) is that column widths in the two divs are independent while in a real table they have to interact. I modified  your jsfiddle to show *that* problem.

Comment: no I *didn't* modify your jsfiddle. I'm trying to figure out how to make a jsfiddle link, then I can demo the thing.

Comment: Again a trick could be to get the `innerHeight()`, `innerWidth()` of the columns and set that at runtime using jQuery or even you can use CSS expressions. Basically you can't give height to tbody as in order to that you'll have to change it's `display` to `block` but it will break the table.

Comment: Hmmmmmm. That would work absolutely stupendous iff I can convinced my brain cell to figure it out. Will you sit and hold my hand on this problem? I'll offer you a ***200-pt bounty!!*** if I (really: you :-) can get this working. Can you check back here in an hour or so; and then every once in a while? I'll have questions for you. I'd appreciate it. Or else we can talk via email: pete at pwilson dot net . Thanks so much!

Comment: Uh-oh! No innerWidth/Height for other than the window element. Back to the drawing board :-)

Answer (score 2):

I ended up modeling the "solution" on the suggestion of @Naveed Ahmad. I put the data part of the table in a <tbody>; and made a fake <thead> that I filled in at onLoad time by referring to the widths and offsets of the <td>s in the first table row, like this:

```
function position_col_heads ( ) {
  // get all the TD child elements from the first row
  var tds = main_tbody.children[0].getElementsByTagName('TD'); 
  for ( var i = 0; i < tds.length; ++i ) {
    thead.children[i].style.left =
      parseFloat( tds[i].offsetLeft ) + 'px';
    thead.children[i].style.width = 
      parseFloat( tds[i].scrollWidth ) + 'px';
  }
}
```

This works more or less OK [**on this page**](http://www.sellmycalls.com/cgi-bin/chain).