# similar tables looking different in opera and IE7

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to achieve a basic fixed table header effect. For this I'm using two tables with the exact same markup and CSS. The "content" table is in a div with overflow-y set. Everything looks fine except IE7 and Opera where the "header" table has different column widths than the "content" table.

Here is a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gEtGW/1/

Please let me know if you have an idea about this.

Thanks!

EDIT:

[image: http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/194/screenshot20110926at114.png/]

[image: http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/687/screenshot20110926at114.png/]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I had this exact same problem and I first tried to solve it in the same way you are doing it. But that led nowhere -- just because of the kinds of cross-browser issues you're seeing. I spent days and days trying to make it right. I finally gave up on the two-table approach. Instead, I made a div with the table header material, calculating the width of each header element from the first row of the content table. It has worked flawlessly in all browsers. I posed a question like yours [**over here on SO**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5703393/is-there-a-css3-way-to-fix-a-thead-on-the-y-axis-let-it-scroll-on-the-x-axis). You might want to give it a look.

Here is [**the table using the new scheme.**](http://www.sellmycalls.com/cgi-bin/chain)

HTH

Answer (score 0):

In your HTML, you have this...

```
<table class="inner-table">
    <colgroup>
        <col width="83">
        <col width="92">
        <col width="123">
        <col width="120">
        <col width="177">
        <col width="84">
    </colgroup>
```

Where the widths above all add up to 679 total.

However, in your CSS, you have this...

```
.inner-table {
    width: 680px;
}
```

I'm not sure what each browser is supposed to do with the extra/missing pixel or how they decide whether the one pixel discrepancy is one extra pixel or missing one pixel.  679 versus 680... which one takes precedence?

Though, I'm sure every browser will probably render this differently.

Comment: @A.Quiroga, the 1 pixel right border is applied to **all** `th` elements within the `thead` which is outside of the `colgroup`.  This just adds another 6 pixels to the whole thing.  Either way, mixing HTML attributes with CSS styles is probably at the root of this rendering discrepancy.

Comment: I only added the width because Opera, for example, extends the table if the container grows :(

Comment: @Sparky672 not only the thead: }
.inner-table tbody tr.even td {
    background-color: #F5F4F0;
    border-right: 1px solid #D7D6D3;
}

Comment: @lucassp, nonetheless, each browser is going to handle discrepancies within the code differently.

Comment: would it be better to add a class to each <col> tag and then add width  to the class instead of the tag?

Comment: @A.Quiroga, I don't know what you're looking at but `.inner-table thead th {...}` is very specifically pointing to one thing... all `th` elements within `thead` within `inner-table`.

Comment: @lucassp, It would be best to style it completely in CSS but I don't even know how big of a difference you're seeing between browsers.  I generally would suggest that you accept the fact that small rendering differences are expected.  How much time should be invested in something that's nearly identical?

Comment: I totally agree that some differences might show up on older browsers, but I didn't expect the latest Opera to have issues. The client never understands this. Even IE8 works. I've added two images from Opera as a reference.

Comment: @lucassp, which image is which?  And yes, do all your widths with CSS, it should give you more precise control over this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Ok problem found (The problem is a text-style one):

'Column' text is making the bounds of the column celd change

For example change 'column' for 'col' and you see it like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/qYnPU/

Comment: Yes, very weird. The text size is nowhere near the width of the column. I will make a different table header based on div's or ul.