# How to make scrollable table's header fixed using css fixed position property?

Tags: css

I am trying to create an efficient way to create a fixed table header. I already have a javascript version which does make it floating using calculation based on offset. Any kind of help will be great.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes there is, I would have explained it to you but **[Chris Coyer @ CSS-Tricks already made an *epic* screencast on the subject](http://css-tricks.com/video-screencasts/66-table-styling-2-fixed-header-and-highlighting/)**, so I won't bother :)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at a closely-similar question with answers: [Is there a css3 way to fix a <thead> on the y-axis, let it scroll on the x-axis?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5703393/is-there-a-css3-way-to-fix-a-thead-on-the-y-axis-let-it-scroll-on-the-x-axis/6776129#6776129)

I don't know how do this with just CSS. The issue is that you want the header to scroll horizontally, even while it's fixed vertically, and the only way I've found to accomplish the effect is with JavaScript.

HTH

Comment: I know how to make it work using javascript. But I was looking for a way that I can do it directly by making table relatively positioned and have thead position fixed.